# Adding each value to an integer array

Tags: java

Can you help me with my problem? I need to add values to my int array but all I get is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public static void numberSort(){

    int quantity = 0;
    int[] values = new int[quantity];
    int allocate = 0;

    quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many values do you wish to sort? : "));

    for(int x = 0; x <= values.length; x++){
        allocate = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Values you want to sort : "));

        values[allocate] = x;

        System.out.println(values[x]);
    }
```

Comment: `int quantity = 0;
    int[] values = new int[quantity];` You are creating an array with size 0

Comment: Consider mark as correct the answer that help you more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int quantity = 0;    
int[] values = new int[quantity];
```

You're allocating an array with `0` locations, which is effectively a zero-length array. This means that it really doesn't have any valid locations, so you can't store anything into it. This is why you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception when you attempt to store anything inside the array.

You will have to move the line where you allocate `values` to the line *after* the line where you read in the value of `quantity`.

Your next problem is your `for` loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= values.length; x++)
```

Array indices run from `0` to `array.length - 1`. So typically the terminating condition for the `for` loop is `x < values.length`. If this was your code, you wouldn't have seen this exception. However, even if you fix this to make `quantity` a non-zero value, you will get the exception when you attempt to fill the array since `values[array.length]` is out of bounds. So you will have to change your `for` loop to:

```
for(int x = 0; x < values.length; x++)
```

I also noticed that you have `values[allocate] = x;`. What you want is `values[x] = allocate;`, since you want the `x`th element of the array.

Comment: nice catch `values[allocate] = x` +1:D

Answer (score 2):

This line is your problem

```
int quantity = 0;    
int[] values = new int[quantity];
```

You are creating an array with length 0. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

Read more in tutorials: [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

For quick fix in your code just init your array after quantity

```
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many values do you wish to sort? : "));
int[] values = new int[quantity];
```

And in for loop change `<=` to `<` cause arrays starts in 0.

```
for(int x = 0; x < values.length; x++){
 allocate = ...
 values[x] = allocate; // you want to allocate in position "x" allocate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from creating an array of 0 length, your for loop end condition is incorrect. You wrote `x <= values.length`, but you should write `x < values.length`. Since arrays in Java are 0-indexed, that means the valid range of indices are 0 to values.length - 1.

Answer (score 0):

I count three errors in there. The most significant one:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= values.length; x++){
```

Java arrays index from zero - that means that for example an array with `length` of `5` has indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. Anything beyond that in either direction results in the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Because you use `<=`, you read one value beyond what's allowed. Replace it with `<`.

Also, you initialize your array to size zero. That means you can't really use it. Initialize your array with `quantity` only once `quantity` has the correct value!

Finally, I believe you want `values[x] = allocate;`, not vice versa.